# Adding two session variables into MYSQL query

Tags: php, forms, post, mysqli

How can I add 2 session variables into my MYSQL query?

This works, because I only use the variable `$stad`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['stad']   = $_POST['stad'];

//Database connectie
$link = mysqli_connect("*", "*", "*", "entour_nl") or die("Error ". mysqli_error($link));

//Query //
$query = "SELECT * FROM Fissa_test WHERE stad='".$_SESSION['stad']."' AND datum >= CURDATE() ORDER BY datum";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//loop door de resultaten
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

<article class="fissa-item">
    <div class="left-side">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['flyer_url'];?>" href="<?php echo $row['flyer_url'];?>" height="100%" width="100%">
    </div>


    <div class="right-side">
        <h3 class="naam-feest" style="margin-top: 1px;"><?php echo $row['naam_feest'];?></h3>
        <h5 class="line-up"><?php echo $row['line_up'];?></h5>
        <h4 class="info"><?php echo $row['plaats'];?> | <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['datum']));?> | <?php echo $row['tijd'];?> | <?php echo $row['leeftijd'];?></h4>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['ticket_url'];?>"><button class="tickets">KOOP TICKETS</button></a>
    </div>

</article>
<?php
}
?>
<div class="footer">
    <button class="filter" onclick="openNav()">FILTER</button>
</div>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <form action="lit_stad_leeftijd.php" method="post">
        <button name="leeftijd" value="14+">14+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="15+">15+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="16+">16+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="17+">17+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="18+">18+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="21+">21+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="23+">23+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="*">ALL</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I include `$leeftijd`. The query doesn't work.

**lit_stad_leeftijd.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['leeftijd']   = $_POST['leeftijd'];
$_SESSION['stad']       = $_POST['stad'];

//Database connectie
$link = mysqli_connect("*", "*", "*", "*") or die("Error ". mysqli_error($link));

//Query //
$query = "SELECT * FROM Fissa_test WHERE stad='".$_SESSION['stad']."' AND leeftijd='".$_SESSION['leeftijd']."' AND datum >= CURDATE() ORDER BY datum";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//loop door de resultaten
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>

    <article class="fissa-item">
        <div class="left-side">
            <img src="<?php echo $row['flyer_url'];?>" href="<?php echo $row['flyer_url'];?>" height="100%" width="100%">
        </div>

        <div class="right-side">
            <h3 class="naam-feest" style="margin-top: 1px;"><?php echo $row['naam_feest'];?></h3>
            <h5 class="line-up"><?php echo $row['line_up'];?></h5>
            <h4 class="info"><?php echo $row['plaats'];?> | <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['datum']));?> | <?php echo $row['tijd'];?> | <?php echo $row['leeftijd'];?></h4>
            <a href="<?php echo $row['ticket_url'];?>"><button class="tickets">KOOP TICKETS</button></a>
        </div>
    </article>
    <?php
}
?>
<div class="footer">
    <button class="filter" onclick="openNav()">FILTER</button>
</div>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <form action="lit_stad_leeftijd.php" method="post">
        <button name="leeftijd" value="14+">14+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="15+">15+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="16+">16+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="17+">17+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="18+">18+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="21+">21+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="23+">23+</button>
        <button name="leeftijd" value="*">ALL</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The error message I get:**

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/9/f/7/website.nl/httpd.www/fissa/lit_stad_leeftijd.php:16) in /customers/9/f/7/website.nl/httpd.www/fissa/lit_stad_leeftijd.php on line 21 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /customers/9/f/7/website.nl/httpd.www/fissa/lit_stad_leeftijd.php:16) in /customers/9/f/7/website.nl/httpd.www/fissa/lit_stad_leeftijd.php on line 21 Notice: Undefined index: stad in /customers/9/f/7/website.nl/httpd.www/fissa/lit_stad_leeftijd.php on line 22 Notice: Undefined index: stad in /customers/9/f/7/website.nl/httpd.www/fissa/lit_stad_leeftijd.php on line 32
FILTER×

Comment: Try output (`echo`) your `$query`, to see what exactly the query is that is being executed. Try execute it yourself (using phpmyadmin, for example), and see if you get any results. On a side note, don't feed user-submitted data directly into a query. Use prepared statements. It will protect against SQL injections, among many other benefits.

Comment: @RobbieToyota this is the error message i get:

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the value into the `$_SESSION` variable? You could just do

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM Fissa_test 
    WHERE stad='" . $_POST['stad'] . "' 
    AND leeftijd='" . $_POST['leeftijd'] . "' 
    AND datum >= CURDATE() ORDER BY datum";
```

If the variable is still not being added into the query, then the issue may be that you aren't correctly posting the data to this page.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you have posted indicates that you're calling `session_start()` after data has already been sent to the output buffer (and thus sent header information).

The [PHP documentation for `session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) has a note:

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

This means that `session_start()` has to be called before any "HTML output". This includes white space, etc. The simple solution is to simply make `session_start()` the first line of code in your file.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <body>
        [...]
    </body>
</html>
```